# Trying to fit a circle. Data have weights

Tags: fitting

```
data = {{-2.5, 0.0}, {-2, 1.1}, {1, 2.1}, {0, 2.5}, {1, 1.9}, {2, 1.1}, {2.5, 
       0}, {2, -1.3}, {1, -2.2}, {0, -2.5}, {-1, -2.2}, {-2, -1.2}, {-2.5,0}}

w = {.1, .2, .5, .1, .5, .6, .1, .1, .4, .2, .1, .1, .3}
```

(* 1st fitting method - this method works but I do not know how to extract parameters*)

```
 circ = ResourceFunction["CircleFit"][data];
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[data], Red, circ}, Frame -> True]
 circ["Properties"]
 circ["ParameterErrors"]
```

(* 2nd fitting method - this method does not do anything*)

```
 s = FindFit[data, y0 - Sqrt[R^2 - (x - x0)^2], {x0, y0, R}, x]
 Print["  x0 =  ", x0];
 Print["  y0 =  ", y0];
 Print["  R =  ", R];
 s["Properties"]
 s["ParameterErrors"]
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[data], Red, s}, Frame -> True]
```

(* 3rd fitting method - this method does not do anything*)

```
 nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2 , {a, b, r}, {x, y}, 
 Weights -> w]
 nlm["FitCurvatureTable"]
 nlm["Properties"]
 nlm["ParameterErrors"]
 Print["  r =  ", r];
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[data], Red, nlm}, Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{-2.5, 0.0}, {-2, 1.1}, {1, 2.1}, {0, 2.5}, {1, 1.9}, {2, 1.1}, {2.5, 
    0}, {2, -1.3}, {1, -2.2}, {0, -2.5}, {-1, -2.2}, {-2, -1.2}, {-2.5, 0}};

w = {.1, .2, .5, .1, .5, .6, .1, .1, .4, .2, .1, .1, .3};

circ = ResourceFunction["CircleFit"][w -> data]

(* Circle[{-0.0526018, -0.0933722}, 2.37452] *)

Graphics[{Blue, circ, Red,
  {AbsolutePointSize[3 + 10*#[[1]]], Tooltip[Point[#[[2]]], #[[1]]]} & /@
   Transpose[{w, data}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The weighted mean of the error is

```
(RegionDistance[circ, #] & /@ data) . (w/Total[w])

(* 0.0643288 *)
```

The weighted root mean square of the error is

```
Sqrt[(RegionDistance[circ, #]^2 & /@ data).(w/Total[w])]

(* 0.0843077 *)
```

Answer (score 5):

To get `NonlinearModelFit` working `data`has to be modified:

```
dataR = Map[Append[#, 0 ] &, data]
circle = NonlinearModelFit[dataR, (x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 - r^2, {x0, y0, r}, {x, y}, Weights -> w]
circle["BestFitParameters"]
(*{x0 -> -0.0531894, y0 -> -0.0890879, r -> 2.37526}*)

ContourPlot[circle[x, y] == 0, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It now works. But when I want to print fitted values I just get symbols:

Comment: I meant: Print["  x0 =  ", x0];Print["  y0 =  ", y0];Print["  R =  ", r]; Out:  x0 =  x0,  y0 =  y0,  R =  r, although it prints: {x0 -> -0.0531894, y0 -> -0.0890879, r -> 2.37526}. I need to have access to these values in my program.

Comment: `circle["BestFitParameters"]` gives rules in the form `{x0 -> -0.0531894, y0 -> -0.0890879, r -> 2.37526}`.  This rules are sufficient to work furtheron with these results. For example `Print["x0=",x0 /. {x0 -> -0.0531894, y0 -> -0.0890879, r -> 2.37526}]`

Answer (score 1):

I can add to the answers by [Bob](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259173/280) and [Ulrich](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259177/280) that if you wish to reproduce with `NonlinearModelFit` the exact results of [`CircleFit`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CircleFit), you must proceed in the two steps as it is clear from the documentation for the latter:

```
Block[{x, y, x0, y0, r, dataR = Map[Append[#, 0] &, data]},
 startingFit = 
  NonlinearModelFit[
   dataR, (x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 - r^2, {x0, y0, r}, {x, y}, 
   Weights -> w];
 finalFit = 
  NonlinearModelFit[dataR, Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2] - r, 
   List @@@ startingFit["BestFitParameters"], {x, y}, Weights -> w]]
```

> [image: output]

```
Clear[x0, y0, r];
circle = Circle[{x0, y0}, r];
startingFitCircle = circle /. startingFit["BestFitParameters"]
finalFitCircle = circle /. finalFit["BestFitParameters"]
```

> ```
> Circle[{-0.0531894, -0.0890879}, 2.37526]
>
> Circle[{-0.0526018, -0.0933722}, 2.37452]
> ```

Now you have access to all properties of the `FittedModel` returned by `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
finalFit["Properties"] // Length
finalFit["ParameterErrors"]
```

> ```
> 50
>
> {0.0415283, 0.0388263, 0.0285003}
> ```

You can direcltly assign the best fit values to the variables by evaluating:

```
Set @@@ finalFit["BestFitParameters"];
```

Now the variables have corresponding values:

```
{x0, y0, r}
```

> ```
> {-0.052601789245274866`, -0.09337216511946304`, 2.3745177111530955`}
> ```

(Note that here I use `0` as the starting radius for the circle in the first fit, while `CircleFit` computes some "optimal" starting value. It results in slightly different final values of the fit parameters. You can get more precise fit by increasing the value of the `PrecisionGoal` option.)

Comment: How do I access the actual variables x0,y0,r so I can use them in later code ?

Comment: @Jerry `finalFit["BestFitParameters"]`.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I need it as x0,y0,r, variables so I can do a calculation later on in my code. When I do a Print statement I do not get right values.

Comment: @Jerry I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Alexey: But when I do Print["  x0fit =  ", x0fit];
Print["  y0fit =  ", y0fit];
Print["  rfit =  ", rfit];, I get nonsensical values. I need to use fitted result in a form of variables.

Comment: Just use `x0`, `y0`, `r` as variables instead of `x0fit` etc. Or evaluate the following: `{x0fit, y0fit, rfit} = finalFit["BestFitParameters"][[All, 2]];`.

Comment: I had an error. Now I get the values. Thanks for help on this one. How do I access fitted results using ResourceFunction["CircleFit"][w -> data] ?

Comment: You should learn very basics on how variable assignment work in *Mathematica*, and also what is a *Mathematica* expression internally. Please consult with some tutorial for beginners. This Is out of scope of this question.